# Mainnet sync Broken

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization, ropsten, peers

I am having a **Mainnet** on Azure VM which was syncing the network as expected, but mean while after adding **Ropsten** network syncing on the same VM simultaneously I'm facing problem with **Mainnet sync broken**.
`Error: WARN [12-17|03:15:53.236] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=a542d5b1be9f0904 err=timeout`

`WARN [12-17|03:15:43.700] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=35892bbf772089d1 err="action from bad peer ignored"`

`WARN [12-17|05:32:29.430] Synchronisation failed, retrying         err="block body download canceled (requested)"`

I'm having Geth version: 1.8.17-stable